# How to link a third-party static library with the newly created cmake project?

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

I have a static library built for arm64-v8a architecture. I need to write a wrapper to call one of the main function of the static library and pass the result to java code. For this I have create a new native project in android studio and added the static library in cpp folder as mylib.a.
I have tried to add this library in CMakeLists.txt but the project is not compiling. Below is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        native-lib

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        native-lib.cpp)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        mylib

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        STATIC

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        mylib.a)

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log)

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        native-lib

        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib}
        ${mylib})
```

I am newbie to CMake. Please help me to link the static library with my shared library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake accesses prebuilt libraries via an imported library: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries

```
add_library(mylib
    STATIC
    IMPORTED
    mylib.a)
```